# How does the system enforce correct execution of smart contracts?

Tags: mining, security, consensus, cryptography

If I understand correctly, the smart contracts are run by the miners. What incentive do the miners have to execute the smart contracts correctly? What stops a malicious miner from changing the result, or a simply lazy miner from doing a simpler computation?

In bitcoin, the proof-of-work is hard to calculate but easy to verify. I don't expect this to be true of all contracts.

Answer (score 8):

Every full node will run the same contract with the same input (with the goal of checking the output).

So,  when a miner runs a contract and notes its execution in a published block,  every full node then runs the same contract (with same inputs) for themselves, in order to verify the output of the miner.   If the output if different,  then the block is rejected.

Therefore,  the miner's incentive is that the block will be rejected if the miner does not process the contract correctly or maliciously - the consensus process!

Answer (score 4):

Every full node verifies every contract execution, so they will not relay invalid blocks, and miners will not mine on top of invalid blocks.

This does mean that calculation on Ethereum is relatively inefficient, since the computation must be carried out by every node, but there are [techniques](http://www.ethereum-computation-market.com/) for moving computation off the blockchain in a secure manner.

Comment: Okay, so smart contracts are intended to be cheap then. Right?

Comment: There is a very small amount of computation available per block, and thus computation can be somewhat expensive (not exorbitantly so, still under $0.01 per transaction). Thus, it is in the designer's best interest to only put critical components on the blockchain, usually the money-handling components.

Comment: Is the small amount of computation a hard limit? If so, how does the technique you linked of having the computation be run on-chain if there is a dispute work?

Comment: The amount of computation allowed per block (as measured in `gas` and called the `block gas limit`) is voted up or down by miners. So it is flexible, and will increase as supply of computing power increases. Another thing that can be done to get around the limit, is that large computations can be broken up across multiple blocks, if they need to be run on-chain

Comment: Hopefully [cryptographic obfusication](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27888/what-is-the-state-of-cryptographic-obfuscation-in-2015) becomes practical at some point. It would allow computations to be run and signed in such a way that it couldn't be altered.

Comment: @PyRulez The consensus algorithm already allows that in the context of Ethereum contracts. Tjaden's link shows how some of it can be offloaded from the blockchain, too.

Comment: @NickJohnson obfuscation would mean you wouldn't need consensus since no computation could be forged.

Comment: @PyRulez Consensus means you don't need obfuscation. :)

Comment: @NickJohnson oh yeah, don't get me wrong. What we have now is the best for what we get. I'm just saying that Cryptographic obfuscation than the potential to revolutionize cryptocurrency, and all of cryptography for that matter.

Comment: @PyRulez I'm kind of of the reverse opinion: Development of distributed consensus protocols has made it possible to achieve many of the things dreamed of for obfuscation, and other things besides (preventing double spending, for instance). I'm skeptical that obfuscation protocols will ever be complete enough to permit turing-complete computation, or efficient enough to be practical. In fact, it may even be provably impossible for them to be turing complete.

Comment: @NickJohnson it's already Turing complete (I think), just not efficient enough yet.