# The sequece of operations on blockchain nodes

Tags: blockchain, nodes

I have been trying to understand the sequence of operations that happens on nodes participating in the network,when a transaction is initiated in both mining or non-mining nodes.

What is the sequence of operation happens when a transaction is initiated by a node ?

The following links helps a little.

[How does the system enforce correct execution of smart contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/how-does-the-system-enforce-correct-execution-of-smart-contracts?rq=1)

The following entities needs to be part of the sequence to draw a complete picture how things works. For example; miner,full node,block,global state( address vs nonce) etc

Comment: Found this one for bitcoin, http://spectrum.ieee.org/image/MjA3NDM1OA.jpeg something similar will do good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6414/52) answer to the thread [What diagrams exist to illustrate the Ethereum blockchain creation process?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/what-diagrams-exist-to-illustrate-the-ethereum-blockchain-creation-process).

Behold (and click for big-ness):

[image]